# What do you call someone who says they will do things but doesn't?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, epithet-requests

What do you call someone who says they will do things but doesn't?  And if they do it, they take 6 months rather than the 6 days they said they could but not necessarily specified that they would?

My husband is a tow truck driver, so he barely has spare time as it is. He also has an odd job business, which doesn't get much business.

He still has a heater here at my apartment left from 8 months ago that he was supposed to fix. Still has to fix his truck and put the new motor in it which he still has to drive 2 hours to get, even though he has a perfectly good one right here.

He has also claimed in the last year that by next year (so that'd be pretty much now, right?) he would have rebuilt a tractor, a snowplow, 2 trucks, a house trailer and a flat bed and he was going to build one, and a motorcycle, plus a 3 wheeler, 4 wheeler, help his dad with his house, get him and I a place...I could go on and on.

Yet he barely sees his son and me and hasn't been home for dinner in 6 months because he is busy working. I will admit he has gotten some jobs done but just at max only 2/3 of them.

I think it's more like 1/3 but I'm trying to give him credit. So what would he be called?

Comment: Okay to re-word, in a way I guess he takes on to much work? Takes on more than he can knowingly handle?

Comment: Are you looking for a noun or an adjective? **Unreliable** seems to fit.

Comment: "All talk and no trousers" is a good expression (might be UK only), or just "all talk"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a quote from somewhere, but Google has failed me in finding its source. Maybe I just invented it. Who knows? **When men *say* we're going to do something, we *mean* that we're going to do it. We don't need *"little reminders"* every six bloody months.**

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-all-talk-and-no-action

Comment: Some of us DO need reminders, I would refrain from sexist comments and stereotyping on Male memory capacity

Comment: Hardworking man who doesn't want to disappoint you by telling you "no I don't have time"?????

Comment: What have you called him so far?

Comment: slothful maybe?

Comment: I'd say he's "overcommitted", a "pleaser", "doesn't know when to say no", "eyes are too big for his stomach", etc? My dear wife is much the same way - always has 17 things she wants to do, 24 that are half-started, but nothing ever gets finished.

Comment: A 'gunner' ( i.e. someone who's always saying they're 'gonna do it')!

Comment: I would like to warn you that I perceive complaining here and that it's best to avoid that. I think that you got the point across with the first example (or even with no examples). In the future, please vent before posting the question.

Comment: @JoshuaLamusga - I got the impression that the OP knows that her husband, in what little spare time he has, reads EL&U.

Answer (score 24):

Reasonably unformally, but not vulgar, is **flake** (noun) or **flakey** (adj.) for somebody who is unreliable.

Comment: That's the only one that explicitly expresses the concept asked for in the question.

Comment: A flake will flake-out, indicating something like a neurosis. 66% success rate is not neurotic. That's better than average for software projects.

Comment: This is very apt, but it's worth noting that it's mainly an American word --- it's unusual in British English (and I think also Australian), though not absolutely unknown.

Comment: @PLL - I'm a Kiwi and it's not uncommon here.

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like his heart's in the right place and he's not slacking off, he's just 
[***overambitious***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overambitious) and *bites off more than he can chew.*

Comment: He's an optimist.

Answer (score 15):

I would say he overextends himself. Also, perhaps he has a hard time saying no. Anyway, he doesn't need a label, he needs a hand.

Answer (score 8):

Answering the question in general terms, the word I'd suggest is *procrastinator*.

If the person's slowness at getting round to the tasks is involuntary -- because they simply don't have enough time to do the jobs they said they were going to do -- *over-promiser* or *over-optimist* may be more to the point.

(From your posting, it does sound as though you and your husband need to periodically sit down and prioritize and/or timetable those tasks and/or hand some of them off to other people. Better that, perhaps, than to let your anger continue to build up and fester.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for an adjective, they're definitely unreliable.

Answer (score 4):

I would call him a "**cunctator**" or "**postponer**."

> [**cunctator**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cunctator): someone who postpones work (especially out of laziness or habitual carelessness).

Comment: Well, that certainly *sounds* dirty.

Comment: The only time I heard this word used, it was used as a compliment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_Maximus

Answer (score 2):

**shirker** may be a definition for:

- a person who evades work, duty, responsibility. But it looks like from your description that your husband is also a busy person.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps he is an *optimist*, *overconfident* or *unpredictable*. He might (or might not) be *uncommitted*, *unfocused* or *off-task*.

Idiomatically, you might choose
*in the weeds*, *off the deep end*, *out of his depth*, or perhaps he's just a *poor estimator* and/or *in the dog house*.

Answer (score 0):

"He bites off more than he can chew" is, I believe, an excellent colloquialism referring to this sort of behavior.

Also, "He has great expectations" or "high aspirations" - used in a somewhat ironic/euphemistic sense.